# Conversão de base entre Sistemas de Numeração

Tags: matemática, numeração

Estou estudando Matemática Computacional, mais especificamente Sistemas de Numeração e sua conversão.

Os Sistemas de Numeração são muito utilizados na programação e na computação em geral, então o meu estudo se dirigi mais especificamente aos 4 tipos essenciais utilizados na computação:

1. Sistema decimal N = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
2. Sistema binário N = {0,1}
3. Sistema octal   N = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
4. Sistema hexadecimal N = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F}

**A minha dúvida se restringe a como fazer a conversão de base de modo mais rápido e efetivo?**

**Existe um método ou metodologia para realizar a conversão de base de modo mais rápido e efetivo?**

Sabendo que para se converter um número de uma base para outra é necessário um grande calculo e regras especificas.

---

```
Conversão de Hexadecimal para Decimal

A regra é a mesma da conversão de qualquer sistema de numeração para o decimal.
```

> AFC0,7D = ?
>
> Ax16³ + Fx16² + Cx16¹ + 0x16° + 7x16-¹ + Dx16-²
>
> 10x16³ + 15x16² + 12x16¹ + 0x16° + 7x16-¹ + 13x16-²
>
> `44992,4882810`

---

Perceba acima que o sistema hexadecimal mostrado acima é posicional começando da direita para a esquerda, por isso a base elevada a (16¹, 16°,16-¹) e perceba também que cada digito foi multiplicado por 16 pois o sistema de numeração hexadecimal é composto de base igual a 16. Portanto 16 dígitos distintos.

Comment: Acho que só entendendo cada sistema mesmo, aí a conversão fica mais fluída. Entender a fórmula é mais simples que decorá-la.

Answer (score 3):

As conversões mais simples são as que envolvem bases que são potências entre si.

Exemplo: conversão entre a base 2 e a base 8. Como 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 separamos os algarismos do binário (base 2) em grupos de três (potencia de 2 <sup>-> 3</sup>) algarismos (começando sempre da direita para a esquerda). `11101001=011.101.001`

Tabela de conversão direta binário para octal e vice-versa.

```
binário  |  octal
 000     |     0
 001     |     1
 010     |     2
 011     |     3
 100     |     4
 101     |     5
 110     |     6
 111     |     7
```

Então,

011 na base 2 = 3 na base 8

101 na base 2 = 5 na base 8

001 na base 2 = 1 na base 8

> portanto 11101001<sub>2</sub> = 351<sub>8</sub>

Conversão entre as bases 2 e 16. Como 2<sup>4</sup> = 16, seguindo o processo anterior, basta separarmos em grupos de quatro algarismos (potencia de 2 <sup>-> 4</sup>) e converter cada grupo seguindo uma tabela similar a anterior.

Exemplo 11110101101 = 0111 . 1010 . 1101

Tabela de conversão direta binário para hexadecimal e vice-versa

```
 binário  |  Hexadecimal
 0000     |     0
 0001     |     1
 0010     |     2
 0011     |     3
 0100     |     4
 0101     |     5
 0110     |     6
 0111     |     7
 1000     |     8
 1000     |     9
 1010     |     A
 1011     |     B
 1100     |     C
 1101     |     D
 1110     |     E
 1111     |     F
```

0111 = 7, 1010 = A, 1101= D

> Portanto 11110101101<sub>2</sub> = 7AD<sub>16</sub>

Para as demais conversões é usando a expressão geral que você usou.